# Is it possible to animate a PNG in a website?

Tags: png, animation

We saw this page and wanted to know if anyone can point us in the direction of how this was created?

https://www.zoho.com/creator/

Watch the PNG move and animate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation was built in the code itself (js, html, css)[image]

Comment: thanks - any idea of an easier way to solve this level of animation?

Comment: In order to move the png's you have to write the code and embed it in your site. If you don't know how to do that stick to a gif.

Answer (score 3):

The author of [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), Jon Skinner, wrote a small python script:

> Instead, I wrote a small Python script that takes a collection of PNG
>   frames as input, and emits a single packed PNG file as output, which
>   contains all the differences between the frames, and some JSON
>   meta-data specifying which bits of the packed PNG file correspond to
>   each frame. JavaScript turns the PNG and JSON into an animation, using
>   either the canvas element, or emulating it using overlaid div elements
>   for older browsers.

I can't link the animation here, as it uses javascript to animate itself, but it's all explained [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html), and the source code is available [here](https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Comment: To be honest, i'm not a graphic designer, I was jsut showing this site to my brother (who is). I use some of the other stack exchange sites quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I found APNG format and I have tried to create an animation with PNG format and it works fine. This is the reference of the APNG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Adobe Photoshop to create similar looking animations, even BETTER animations than the one shown in the link, without the knowledge of any CSS3 Animations or JavaScript/jQuery etc.

You can go to Window > Animation in older versions, or Window > Workspace > Motion in the latest version (CC).

Comment: This is 'an easier way to solve the animation trick'!

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

To animate a png inside a webpage you need to know either JavaScript or Css3 animation. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

You also can make an animated gif.

Comment: https://madeinhaus.com/haus-com/master/567b21d/images-apng/work/twitter-happening/icon.png - explain this one please?